# How to set path for installed modules on computer with 2 versions of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I haven't tried yet out of fear I'll mess up more than I'll fix but I don't know if I can use `PYTHONPATH` to fix my problem.  I've installed python 2.7.10 and python 3.4.2 on my Macbookpro.  Python2.7 doesn't have problems, only 3.4 does.  I'm afraid if I use `PYTHONPATH` to fix python3, it will affect python2.

Anyway, I've run:

```
sudo pip install blah2
sudo pip3 install blah3
pip freeze | grep blah2
blah2=2.12345
pip3 freeze | grep blah3
blah3=3.12345
```

and I can see I've installed the respective modules for python2 and python3 as pip freeze has shown.
However, I keep getting errors when running scripts from cmd line for python 3.4 that say the module isn't found.

On further investigation using `sys.path` in my script, I can see python3 from cmd line is looking for modules at

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

which doesn't have anything inside of it, whereas **Idle** for python 3.4 is looking at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

which has tons of files in there.

I don't know why this got messed up in the first place or what I forgot to do to mess it up like this but how do I tell python 3.4 to look at the **/Library** location for modules?

The funny thing is both python2 and 3 were installed from tar/gzip files.  I ran both using the

```
configure; make ;make install
```

command but for some reason python2 is fine but python3 isn't.

Comment: Have you tried out conda or pyenv instead?  There are a handful of tools out there that manage this for you instead of you having to figure out all the weird tricks needed to make it work.

Comment: No, I didn't even know they existed.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may mean the `pip3` is installing to that different path.
Take a look at `pip3` script and see where it is putting the package files. In my case the first line of it looks like this:

```
#!/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
```

Look if this is the path to the correct python3 binary. If it's not, you have two options: change this first line of `pip3` to the path of your desired python3 binary, or just forget about it, use the `pip` directly with `python3` command:

```
python3 -m pip install blah3
```

This should use the appropriate path when installing the package.